# How check if attributes is in declaration Polymer

Tags: attributes, polymer

Lets say I have a custom element defined as

```
<polymer-element name="my-elem" >
<template if={{show_is_in_my_declaration?}}>
   ....
</template>
<script>
Polymer('my-elem', {});
</script>
```

To use it I would like to declare it as...

```
<my-elem show></my-elem>
```

Where including '`show`', makes the template appear; similar to how things like '`flex`' or '`fit`' effect the element. What is this called and how do I implement it.

note: I don't want to write something like `show="{{true}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Conditional Templates.

Here is the docs:
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/template.html#if

and here are some examples on how to use them:
https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/tree/master/examples/how_to